# Split concave into separate convex meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, unity

I know `Mesh > Cleanup > Split Concave Faces` splits the mesh itself into convex shapes, but **I want to split it into separate objects** so I can import it into unity.

That's all I really want to know, how can I make it separate objects that I can select and export individually?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into exactly the same question. I wrote a script that uses the "Split Concave Faces" feature to split the object into separate parts. It's not foolproof -- it only works well for reasonably flat, rectangular geometry.

The hardest parts of the process are:

1. Identifying which edges the object should be split by, since "Split Concave Faces" only adds edges that it deems necessary, but the object may already have edges that define the boundary of a convex region.
2. Intelligently matching up which faces of an object should be grouped together into a new closed object after splitting-up the parent object. For example, two faces that are parallel to one another might end up as separate planes after splitting by convex boundary edges -- so the script must find these and determine that they need to be matched up.

I have not found a feasible way to do either of the above if an object has holes or openings inside -- especially curved openings. It seems that the algorithm can never be sure which edges connect both sides of a convex shape for splitting, and which edges should be left alone because they're part of a closed shape. Meanwhile, once split, knowing the optimal combination of faces to re-combine to form closed shapes becomes intractible because there's no good way to know how many distinct faces/pieces need to be re-combined -- 2? 3?

Anyway, here's a link to the script:
https://gist.github.com/GuyPaddock/e2420a0c54f6892c2c2f01556d6a4e14

It operates on the selected object.

Since this is likely to be used for collision meshes for things like Unreal Engine 4, the script also renames the split pieces according to sequence numbering. Before running the script, give the object you are splitting a name
that ends with `_01` (e.g. `UCX_My_Mesh_01`) so that all the pieces that split off from it are properly (e.g. `UCX_My_Mesh_02`, `UCX_My_Mesh_031`, etc.)
numbered.

In case my link disappears, here's the full script as of the date I am writing this:

```py
##
# A script to split simple, architectural geometry into convex pieces.
#
# This script makes use of Blender's built-in "Split Concave Faces" clean-up
# algorithm to break-up the faces of an object into convex pieces. The script
# attempts to identify all the edges that represent convex boundaries, and then
# it splits objects up along those edges. Each resulting piece is then made into
# a closed object by converting it into a convex hull.
#
# Be sure to select the object you wish the split into convex pieces before
# running the script.
#
# NOTE: This script is expecting to work with flat, reasonably clean geometry.
# For example, it is expected to be used when generating collision on the
# ceiling and walls of an architectural visualization project, but is not
# expected to perform well with round or n-gon geometry. Using 
# create_closed_objects=True and matchup_degenerates=True, in particular, does
# not work well with objects that have openings inside.
#
# If this script doesn't work for you, a plug-in like V-HACD may work better.
# This script was written to handle cases V-HACD did not handle well -- flat,
# reasonably rectangular arch. vis. geometry.
#
# @author Guy Elsmore-Paddock <guy.paddock@gmail.com>
#

import bmesh
import bpy
import operator
import re

from itertools import combinations, count
from math import atan2, pi, radians, degrees
from mathutils import Vector


def split_into_convex_pieces(ob, create_closed_objects=True,
                             matchup_degenerates=True):
    object_name = ob.name

    deselect_all_objects()
    make_all_faces_convex(ob)

    eliminated_piece_names = \
        split_on_convex_boundaries(
            ob,
            create_closed_objects,
            matchup_degenerates
        )

    rename_pieces(object_name, eliminated_piece_names)

    # Deselect everything, for the convenience of the user.
    deselect_all_objects()


def make_all_faces_convex(ob):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    # This is what actually defines the new geometry -- Blender creates the
    # convex shapes we need to split by.
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.vert_connect_concave()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')


##
# Splits an object into smaller pieces by its convex, planar edges.
#
# In an ideal world, we could just split the object by all the edges that are
# attached to -- and are co-planar with -- the faces of the object, since those
# edges are most likely to represent the convex boundaries of the object. But,
# Blender does not provide an easy way to find such edges.
#
# Instead, we use several heuristics to simulate this type of selection:
#   1. First, we select all the sharp edges of the object, since sharp edges are
#      only co-planar with one of the faces they connect with and are therefore
#      unlikely to represent convex boundary edges.
#   2. Second, we select all edges that are similar in angle to the sharp edges,
#      to catch any edges that are almost steep enough to be sharp edges.
#   3. Third, we invert the selection, which should (hopefully) cause all the
#      convex boundary edges we want to be selected.
#   4. Fourth, we seek out any sharp edges that connect with the convex boundary
#      edges, since we will need to split on these edges as well so that our
#      "cuts" go all the way around the object (e.g. if the convex boundary
#      edges lay on the top and bottom faces of an object, we need to select
#      sharp edges to connect the top and bottom edges on the left and right
#      sides so that each split piece is a complete shape instead of just
#      disconnected, detached planes).
#   4. Next, we split the object by all selected edges, which should result in
#      creation of each convex piece we seek.
#
def split_on_convex_boundaries(ob, create_closed_objects=True,
                               matchup_degenerates=True):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    select_convex_boundary_edges(ob)

    # Now perform an vertex + edge split along each selected edge, which should
    # result in the object being broken-up along each planar edge and connected
    # sharp edges (e.g. on corners).
    bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split(type='VERT')

    # Now, just break each loose part off into a separate object.
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')

    if create_closed_objects:
        # And then make each piece fully enclosed.
        return create_closed_shapes_from_pieces(ob, matchup_degenerates)
    else:
        return []


##
# Selects all edges that denote the boundaries of convex pieces.
#
# This is a multi-step process driven by heuristics:
#   1. First, we select all the sharp edges of the object, since sharp edges are
#      only co-planar with one of the faces they connect with and are therefore
#      unlikely to represent convex boundary edges.
#   2. Second, we select all edges that are similar in length to the sharp
#      edges, to catch any edges that are almost steep enough to be sharp edges.
#   3. Third, we invert the selection, which should (hopefully) cause all the
#      convex boundary edges we want to be selected.
#
def select_convex_boundary_edges(ob, max_edge_length_proportion=0.1):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    mesh = ob.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

    # Enter "Edge" select mode
    bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = [False, True, False]

    # Find all sharp edges and edges of similar length
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.edges_select_sharp()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='LENGTH', threshold=0.01)

    # Invert the selection to find the convex boundary edges.
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='INVERT')

    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()

    edges_to_select = []
    max_edge_length = max(ob.dimensions) * max_edge_length_proportion

    for selected_edge in [e for e in bm.edges if e.select]:
        edge_bridges =\
            find_shortest_edge_bridges(
                selected_edge,
                max_edge_length=max_edge_length
            )

        for path in edge_bridges.values():
            for edge in path:
                edges_to_select.append(edge)

    # Select the edges after we pick which edges we *want* to select, to ensure
    # that we only base our decisions on the initial convex boundary edges.
    for edge in edges_to_select:
        edge.select = True


##
# Locate the shortest path of edges to connect already-selected edges.
#
# This is used to find the additional edges that must be selected for a cut
# along a convex boundary to create a complete, closed object shape.
#
# The max edge length argument can be provided to avoid trying to find
# connections between convex boundaries that are very far apart in the same
# object.
#
def find_shortest_edge_bridges(starting_edge, max_edge_length=None):
    edge_bridges = find_bridge_edges(starting_edge, max_edge_length)
    sorted_edge_bridges = sorted(edge_bridges, key=lambda eb: eb[0])
    edge_solutions = {}

    for edge_bridge in sorted_edge_bridges:
        path_distance, final_edge, path = edge_bridge

        # Skip edges we've already found a min-length path to
        if final_edge not in edge_solutions.keys():
            edge_solutions[final_edge] = path

    print(f"Shortest edge bridges for starting edge '{str(starting_edge.index)}':")

    if len(edge_solutions) > 0:
        print(
            "  - " +
            "\n  - ".join(map(
                lambda i: str(
                    (i[0].index, str(list(map(lambda e: e.index, i[1]))))
                ),
                edge_solutions.items()
            )))
    print("")
    print("")

    return edge_solutions


##
# Performs a recursive, depth-first search from a selected edge to other edges.
#
# This returns all possible paths -- and distances of those paths -- to traverse
# the mesh from the starting, selected edge to another selected edge. To avoid
# a lengthy search, the max_depth parameter controls how many levels of edges
# are searched.
#
# The result is an array of tuples, where each tuple contains the total distance
# of the path, the already-selected edge that the path was able to reach, and
# the list of edges that would need to be selected in order to reach that
# destination edge.
#
def find_bridge_edges(edge, max_edge_length=None, max_depth=3, current_depth=0,
                      path_distance=0, edge_path=None, seen_verts=None):
    if edge_path is None:
        edge_path = []

    if seen_verts is None:
        seen_verts = []

    # Don't bother searching edges we've seen
    if edge in edge_path:
        return []

    if (current_depth > 0):
        first_edge = edge_path[0]
        edge_length = edge.calc_length()

        # Don't bother searching edges along the same normal as the first edge.
        # We want our cuts to be along convex boundaries that are perpendicular.
        if have_common_face(first_edge, edge):
            return []

        if edge.select:
            return [(path_distance, edge, edge_path)]

        # Disqualify edges that are too long.
        if max_edge_length is not None and edge_length > max_edge_length:
            print(
                f"Disqualifying edge {edge.index} because length [{edge_length}] > [{max_edge_length}"
            )

            return []

    if current_depth == max_depth:
        return []

    new_edge_path = edge_path + [edge]
    bridges = []

    for edge_vert in edge.verts:
        # Don't bother searching vertices we've already seen (no backtracking).
        if edge_vert in seen_verts:
            continue

        new_seen_verts = seen_verts + [edge_vert]

        for linked_edge in edge_vert.link_edges:
            # Don't bother searching selected edges connected to the starting
            # edge, since that gets us nowhere.
            if linked_edge.select and current_depth == 0:
                continue

            edge_length = linked_edge.calc_length()

            found_bridge_edges = find_bridge_edges(
                edge=linked_edge,
                max_edge_length=max_edge_length,
                max_depth=max_depth,
                current_depth=current_depth + 1,
                path_distance=path_distance + edge_length,
                edge_path=new_edge_path,
                seen_verts=new_seen_verts
            )

            bridges.extend(found_bridge_edges)

    return bridges


def create_closed_shapes_from_pieces(ob, matchup_degenerates=True,
                                     min_volume=0.1):
    print("Converting each piece into a closed object...")

    degenerate_piece_names = []

    for piece in name_duplicates_of(ob):
        if not make_piece_convex(piece):
            degenerate_piece_names.append(piece.name)

    degenerate_count = len(degenerate_piece_names)

    print("")
    print(f"Total degenerate (flat) pieces: {degenerate_count}")
    print("")

    eliminated_piece_names = []

    if matchup_degenerates:
        if degenerate_count > 10:
            # TODO: Hopefully, some day, find a good deterministic way to
            # automatically match up any number of degenerate pieces using a
            # heuristic that generates sane geometry.
            print(
                "There are too many degenerates for reliable auto-matching, so "
                "it will not be performed. You will need to manually combine "
                "degenerate pieces.")
            print("")
        else:
            eliminated_piece_names.extend(
                matchup_degenerate_pieces(degenerate_piece_names, min_volume)
            )

            eliminated_piece_names.extend(
                eliminate_tiny_pieces(degenerate_piece_names, min_volume)
            )

    return eliminated_piece_names


def matchup_degenerate_pieces(degenerate_piece_names, min_volume=0.1):
    pieces_eliminated = []
    degenerate_volumes = find_degenerate_combos(degenerate_piece_names)

    print("Searching for a way to match-up degenerates into volumes...")

    for piece1_name, piece1_volumes in degenerate_volumes.items():
        # Skip pieces already joined with degenerate pieces we've processed
        if piece1_name not in degenerate_piece_names:
            continue

        piece1 = bpy.data.objects[piece1_name]

        piece1_volumes_asc = dict(
            sorted(
                piece1_volumes.items(),
                key=operator.itemgetter(1)
            )
        )

        piece2 = None

        for piece2_name, combo_volume in piece1_volumes_asc.items():
            # Skip pieces that would make a volume that's too small, or that
            # have been joined with degenerate pieces we've processed
            if combo_volume < min_volume or piece2_name not in degenerate_piece_names:
                continue
            else:
                piece2 = bpy.data.objects[piece2_name]
                break

        if piece2 is not None:
            degenerate_piece_names.remove(piece2.name)
            pieces_eliminated.append(piece2.name)

            print(
                f"  - Combining parallel degenerate '{piece1.name}' with "
                f"'{piece2.name}' to form complete mesh '{piece1.name}'."
            )

            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = piece1

            piece1.select_set(True)
            piece2.select_set(True)

            bpy.ops.object.join()

            make_piece_convex(piece1)

    return pieces_eliminated


def find_degenerate_combos(degenerate_piece_names):
    volumes = {}

    for piece_combo in combinations(degenerate_piece_names, 2):
        piece1_name, piece2_name = piece_combo
        piece1 = bpy.data.objects[piece1_name]
        piece2 = bpy.data.objects[piece2_name]

        if not volumes.get(piece1_name):
            volumes[piece1_name] = {}

        piece1_mesh = piece1.data
        piece1_bm = bmesh.new()
        piece1_bm.from_mesh(piece1_mesh)

        piece2_mesh = piece2.data
        piece2_bm = bmesh.new()
        piece2_bm.from_mesh(piece2_mesh)

        piece1_bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
        piece2_bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

        if (len(piece1_bm.faces) == 0) or (len(piece2_bm.faces) == 0):
            continue

        piece1_face = piece1_bm.faces[0]
        piece2_face = piece2_bm.faces[0]

        combo_angle_radians = piece1_face.normal.angle(piece2_face.normal)
        combo_angle_degrees = int(round(degrees(combo_angle_radians)))

        # We only combine faces that are parallel to each other
        if combo_angle_degrees in [0, 180]:
            combo_volume = convex_volume(piece1, piece2)

            volumes[piece1.name][piece2.name] = combo_volume

    return volumes


def eliminate_tiny_pieces(degenerate_piece_names, min_volume=0.1):
    eliminated_piece_names = []

    tiny_piece_names = [
        n for n in degenerate_piece_names
        if n not in eliminated_piece_names
           and convex_volume(bpy.data.objects.get(n)) < min_volume
    ]

    print("")
    print(f"Total remaining tiny pieces: {len(tiny_piece_names)}")

    # Delete tiny pieces that are too small to be useful
    for tiny_piece_name in tiny_piece_names:
        print(f"  - Eliminating tiny piece '{tiny_piece_name}'...")

        tiny_piece = bpy.data.objects[tiny_piece_name]

        bpy.data.objects.remove(tiny_piece, do_unlink=True)
        eliminated_piece_names.append(tiny_piece_name)

    print("")

    return eliminated_piece_names


def make_piece_convex(ob, min_volume=0.1):
    print(
        f"  - Attempting to make '{ob.name}' into a closed, convex "
        f"shape."
    )

    volume_before = convex_volume(ob)

    make_convex_hull(ob)

    volume_after = convex_volume(ob)
    volume_delta = abs(volume_after - volume_before)

    # If the volume of the piece is very small when we tried making it convex,
    # then it's degenerate -- it's a plane or something flat that we need to
    # remove.
    is_degenerate = (volume_after < min_volume)

    print(f"    - Volume before: {volume_before}")
    print(f"    - Volume after: {volume_after}")
    print(f"    - Volume delta: {volume_delta}")
    print(f"    - Is degenerate: {is_degenerate}")

    return not is_degenerate


def make_convex_hull(ob):
    deselect_all_objects()

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    ob.select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.convex_hull()

    mesh = ob.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

    # Clean-up unnecessary edges
    bmesh.ops.dissolve_limit(
        bm,
        angle_limit=radians(5),
        verts=bm.verts,
        edges=bm.edges,
    )

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')


def have_common_normal(e1, e2):
    e1_normals = map(lambda f: f.normal, e1.link_faces)
    e2_normals = map(lambda f: f.normal, e2.link_faces)

    common_normals = [n for n in e1_normals if n in e2_normals]

    return len(common_normals) > 0


def have_common_face(e1, e2):
    common_faces = [f for f in e1.link_faces if f in e2.link_faces]

    return len(common_faces) > 0


def convex_volume(*obs):
    meshes = []
    verts = []

    for ob in obs:
        mesh = ob.data
        bm = bmesh.new()

        bm.from_mesh(mesh)

        bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
        bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

        # Prevent early garbage collection.
        meshes.append(bm)

        geom = list(bm.verts) + list(bm.edges) + list(bm.faces)

        for g in geom:
            if hasattr(g, "verts"):
                verts.extend(v.co for v in g.verts)
            else:
                verts.append(g.co)

    return build_volume_from_verts(verts)


def build_volume_from_verts(verts):
    # Based on code from:
    # https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107357/how-to-find-if-geometry-linked-to-an-edge-is-coplanar
    origin = sum(verts, Vector((0, 0, 0))) / len(verts)
    bm = bmesh.new()

    for v in verts:
        bm.verts.new(v - origin)

    bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=bm.verts)

    return bm.calc_volume()


def deselect_all_objects():
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    except:
        pass


def rename_pieces(object_name, name_skiplist=None):
    if name_skiplist is None:
        name_skiplist = []

    for duplicate_name, old_index_str, new_index in dupe_name_sequence(object_name, name_skiplist):
        piece = bpy.data.objects.get(duplicate_name)

        if not piece:
            break

        old_name = piece.name
        new_name = re.sub(fr"(?:01)?\.{old_index_str}$", f"{new_index:02d}", piece.name)

        if old_name != new_name:
            print(f"Renaming piece '{old_name}' to '{new_name}'.")
            piece.name = new_name


def name_duplicates_of(ob):
    duplicates = []

    for duplicate_name, _, _ in dupe_name_sequence(ob.name):
        piece = bpy.data.objects.get(duplicate_name)

        if not piece:
            break
        else:
            duplicates.append(piece)

    return duplicates


def dupe_name_sequence(base_name, skiplist=None):
    if skiplist is None:
        skiplist = []

    yield base_name, "", 1

    new_index = 1

    for old_name_index in count(start=1):
        old_index_str = f"{old_name_index:03d}"
        duplicate_name = f"{base_name}.{old_index_str}"

        if duplicate_name in skiplist:
            continue
        else:
            new_index = new_index + 1

            yield duplicate_name, old_index_str, new_index


split_into_convex_pieces(bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active)
print("Done!")
```

I added screenshots to the gist:
https://gist.github.com/GuyPaddock/e2420a0c54f6892c2c2f01556d6a4e14#gistcomment-3631462

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Would you mind adding the script into the body of the answer for posterity ? External links can be erased or go private without warning.

Comment: I can when it's more finalized. I'm finding that it's only working for the first set of objects I tested with but isn't working more generally.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: its not possible.
You have to do it manually.

Good thing it was a small model, my condolences to anyone with a large model and the same problem. Hopefully, someone will make an addon that can do this one day.